# Confusion when trying to compute a conditional expectation

Tags: probability

If $X$ and $Y$ are independent uniform rv on $(0,1)$, I want to Compute $E(X \mid X < Y )$.

### Try

By definition, what I am looking for is

$$ E(X \mid X < Y) = \int_0^1 x f_{X \mid X<Y} (x|y) dx $$

now, we have

$$ f_{X \mid X<Y} (x|y) = \frac{ P(X < x, X<Y) }{P(X<Y)} = 2 P(X <x, X<Y)$$

Since $P(X<Y) = 1/2$. Now, here where I find really troublesome the notation to work with. how we compute expression of the form $P(X<x, X<Y)$? Now, this is supposed to be adouble integral where we integrate over the region $\{ (x,y): x<x, x<y \} $? but this region is triangular with area $x^2/2$ and so the required value is

$$ \int_0^1 x x^2 = x^4/4 |_0^1 = 1/4 $$

but, the answer is supposed to be $1/6$. what is wrong in my calculation?

Comment: Note that a PDF is different from a CDF.  I think you mean $F_{X|X<Y}(x)= \frac{P[X\leq x, X<Y]}{P[X<Y]}$ (and note this has no dependence on a variable "$y$"). Its derivative $f_{X|X<Y}(x)$ also has no dependence on a variable "$y$." You may also want to double-check by drawing the (trapezoid) region in the unit square of all $(X,Y)$ associated with $\{X<x, X<Y\}$. This region depends on a value "$x$."

Comment: Weird, I get an answer of 1/3.

Comment: @norfair : The answer is $1/3$ but that is not why the above calculation is wrong.

Comment: The OP claims that the answer is 1/6.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find conditional expectation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3006515/find-conditional-expectation)

Comment: Im asking for comments on my calculation. What I did wrong

Comment: @JimmySabater The distribution of $X\mid X<Y$ is the same as that of $\min(X,Y)$.

Comment: @JimmySabater : If you are interested in corrections on your work, you can re-read the very first comment above, for example, do you (now?) agree that a probability density function (PDF) is not the same thing as a cumulative distribution function (CDF)?