# Conditional expectation using conditional PDF

Tags: probability, expected-value

The joint probability density function for two random variables X and Y is given by $f_{XY}(x,y)=1 $  $(0<x<1), (0<y<1)$.

and the conditional joint PDF is $f_{XY}(x,y | X>Y)=2 $ $(0<x<y<1))$ by bayes' theorem.

Thus, the conditional marginal PDF is $f_{X}(x | X>Y)= \int_{0}^y 2dy=2x   $ $(0<x<y<1))$

I'd like to calculate the conditional expectation and I have a little confusion here : whether I should use $E(X|X>Y)=\int_{0}^12xdx$ or $E(X|X>Y)=\int_{y}^12xdx$.

Comment: So the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f_{X,Y}(x,y)= \mathbb{1}_{0<x<1}\mathbb{1}_{0<y<1}$ and $f_X(x) = \int f_{X,Y}(x,y)dy$. We know that $E[X|X>Y]=\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{X>Y}]}{P(X>Y)}$. I think you have all the ingredients to compute the expectation.

Comment: How does E[X|X>Y]=E[X|X>Y]P(X>Y) hold? It doesn't make sense.

Comment: Look at this [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_expectation#Conditional_expectation_with_respect_to_an_event)

Comment: You are overthinking. What you have is two independent $U(0,1)$ variables. See  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3006539/321264, which is in the same spirit as the answer below.

Answer (score 3):

We know that $E[X|X>Y]=\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{X>Y}]}{P(X>Y)}$. Therefore,
\begin{align}
E[X|X>Y] &= \frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{X>Y}]}{P(X>Y)} \\
&=\frac{\int_0^1\int_0^1x\mathbb{1}_{x\geq y}dxdy}{\int_0^1\int_0^1\mathbb{1}_{x\geq y}dxdy} \\
&= \frac23
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) It is enough to directly say $P(X>Y)=1/2$ using symmetry.